# iCheck checkboxes not displaying

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, checkbox, asset-pipeline, icheck

I can't get the [iCheck iCheckbox plugin](https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck) to display in any browser.

Here is a jSFiddle. iCheck depends on jQuery 1.7+.

http://jsfiddle.net/jmj3M/2/

I have it initialized without any options:

```
$(".ex-f").iCheck();
```

As you can see if you inspect the DOM, the input element is being wrapped by the iCheckbox div. Both the `<input>` and `<ins>` elements have their opacity set to 0, however.

Changing their opacity via jQuery, you get this: http://jsfiddle.net/buRq7/

Unfortunately, it still does not work. Does anyone have any advice or experience on getting this to work?

I'm using rails 4 and the asset pipeline.

**EDIT:** 
I just realized I selected no-library (pure JS) as a framework option in jsFiddle, and it seems to work even without changing the opacity (see: http://jsfiddle.net/buRq7/5/). However, the documentation explicitly says that it depends on jQuery (or Zepto). Switching the framework option to jQuery 1.10.1 leads to the iCheckbox no longer functioning again ... not sure why this is.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: No I never figured it out. Haven't been able to look into it much beyond the above, maybe I'll take another shot at it soon. Let me know if you figure it out.

Answer (score 23):

just .iCheck() without any parameter won't work. You need the following at least:

```
 $('input').iCheck({
            checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal-grey',
            radioClass: 'iradio_minimal-grey'
        });
```

Comment: They never said this in documentation :D

Comment: Their documentation is pretty confusing. Thanks for saving me so much time!

Comment: Having same issue and parameters are set, it appears to be a conflict but so far don't have the time to track it down.

Answer (score 6):

Choose a skin and import the css for selected one:

```
<link href="http://fronteed.com/iCheck/skins/all.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="http://fronteed.com/iCheck/icheck.js"></script>
```

and to load the iCheck you can use, for example:

```
$(".ex-f").iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal',
    radioClass: 'iradio_minimal'
});
```

Check it at: http://jsfiddle.net/a4p6kjb9/

Answer (score 2):

I noticed also that using wrong `css` file and not including the correct `png` can cause this `iCheck` not to work properly.

So the `css` file you choose must correspond to the `checkboxClass` and `radioClass` you set.

Answer (score 1):

So I was having the same issue, it might be related to newer version of jQuery, but you need to specity the input type with your selector:​

```
$("input[type='checkbox'], input[type='radio']").iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal',
    radioClass: 'iradio_minimal'
});
```